# How Can I make a JPEG appear some error with python?

Tags: python, jpeg

I was looking for a python library that would cause errors in JPEG images with a certain BER(Block Error Rate in communication).
And I had google it. But I don't find something about it.Can anyone help me? Thanks.

Comment: Such kinds of "seek library" will soon be closed by guys. Just a query for OP, does anyone know which site could accept such kinds of queries? I feel "such query" really useful sometimes, and really cherish the memory of those days years ago when such questions will not out of scope.

Comment: Start with coding. When you encounter problems, ask specific questions. SO won't give recommendations on libraries and tools. Also, read [ask] and take the [tour].

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.